# How to debug Haxe using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe

I'm trying to debug a Haxe application with cpp target using IntelliJ IDEA.
Every time i got same error while trying to run debug on it: 
["You can debug only flash or HXCPP targets"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibh51.png)

I have a basic HelloWorld project setup with the Haxe compiler and the C++ target ([setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wylzj.png)).

I'm using latest plugin for Haxe (0.9.10) and hxcpp-debugger with old protocol version (as mentioned in haxe plugin description). Tried this on IDEA14, 15 & 2016.

All guides that I found to make it work looks outdated.

Comment: For Flash debugging, [YouTube video to Setup Haxe OpenFL IntelliJ IDEA development environment](https://youtu.be/kvFg1Zee4h4)

Answer (score 1):

the closest i found is this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JjgOrEXcQc - it uses openfl, but if you look at the logging window, it outputs a command : `haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml haxe -Ddebug -DHXCPP -Dcpp -Ddebug -Ddesktop -Dhaxe_208 -Dhaxe_209 -Dhaxe_210 -Dhxcpp -Dnme -Dnme_install_tool -Dsys -Dtrue -Dwindows`. You'd have to make your build run that same command if you're not using openfl to build.

The code must also create a debug socket server somewhere in your `main` method:

`new DebugSocket("127.0.0.1", 65333, true)`